# CSS : Overwriting using style tag on JSP page

Tags: html, css, jsp, tiles

I do not use CSS at all as i develop back end so i have very little exposure to it.

I have a webpage that is styled using multiple CSS files but the screen is stretched across the whole page. What i would like is to make the screen a bit thinner and add a background from a .PNG file. When ever i add the following code to my .JSP page to load the .PNG file nothing happens

```
<style type="text/css">
html { 
  background: url(<c:url value="/resources/blue-back-grade-2.png"/>) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.box{-moz-box-shadow: 10px  10px  5px  #555555;-webkit-box-shadow: 10px  10px  5px  #555555;box-shadow: 10px  10px  5px  #555555;}
a {
    color: #04315E;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: small;
    text-decoration: none;
    a:hover 
}
.hov { color: #04315E; }
.hov:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
.hov:active { color: #04315E; }
.hov:visited { color: #04315E; }

.no-hov { color: #04315E; }
.no-hov:hover { text-decoration: none; }
td img {
    display: block;
}
td img {
    display: block;
}
td img {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}td img {display: block;}
</style>
```

Is it a matter that the page needs to be thinner for the background image to be picked up or is this CSS code being overwritten somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

If the url of the image is dynamic then set it using javascript or jquery otherwise store it in external css file as relative url.

Read more about [CSS Background](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwi-wYr_sZTHAhWBMIgKHexZBRQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fcss%2Fcss_background.asp&ei=_0nDVf7FLYHhoATss5WgAQ&usg=AFQjCNHy0FYEdp8OABfZBe4u0kj1J-cr9g&bvm=bv.99556055,d.cGU)

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url("paper.gif");
}
```

How to set the body background image if url is dynamic:

```
$('body').css('background-image','url(image_url)');
```

Sample code using `JQuery` to set the background image of page.

```css
#containier{
   height : 150px;
   width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="containier"></div>

<script>
$('#containier').css('background-image','url(https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTn2GsaEpA1X8Omt-dxlm7aYLS0CIgF0N2HDqVmtWLEr2uD_WM4)');
</script>
```